# FloatingActionButton inside framelayout not working

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-framelayout

I want to display text instead of icon on FloatingActionButton. Hence, I made use of FrameLayout to achieve this. However, none of the onClickListerners are working. I have set`android:clickable="true"` still no change.
Below is my sample layout file:

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="7dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text="My Text"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I tried using both methods:
1. setting `android:onClick="myMethod"`
2. setting onClickListener programmatically on all the three elements i.e. FrameLayout, FAB and TextView inside Activity class

However, i use FAB normally, i.e. without using FrameLayout; it is working fine.

Please provide some solution.

EDIT : Activity.java

```
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myMethod();
        }
    });

    text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myMethod();
        }
    });

    frame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myMethod();
        }
    });
```

Logger implementation present inside myMethod(). It seems onClick event is not getting triggered, as I cannot see any log in the console.

Update::
The layout file also contains RecyclerView at the same level that of FrameLayout. Does the problem occur due to presence of RecyclerView?

Comment: remove `android:clickable="true"` from framelayout..

Comment: please post your click event code

Comment: is it important to use Floating Button? coz.. you can achieve same by setting round shape background to button.

Comment: @ Uttam, Button will have fixed position. My view contains recycler view. So I want button to be floating over the list item

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resloved. I set `android:layout_anchor` on FrameLayout to recycler view id. Now the button is clickable.